# iphone, can we set the option 'Send From' of the email when use MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone

as topic.... I just want change the value 'Send From' when compose new email. but seem it is impossible......

anyone can give tips ?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, only the user can change it once they are in the `MFMailComposeViewController` view by tapping on the "From:" field and selecting their various e-mail address from the picker view.

For future reference, unless something like this is in the class reference, you probably can't do it without accessing private API (which is a no-no).

Class reference: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html